# Set position Persian letter in text only with css

Tags: css, farsi

I have text like this:

[image]

I want to show this text (`36 و 534 12`) in a div

if set `direction: rtl` for div, the text is shown like this

[image]

and if set `direction: ltr` for div, the text is shown like this

[image]

how can I show this text like first image in my div only with css ?

Comment: Can you add the symbol as a text in your question? so people will be able to check it

Comment: the symbol is "و"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of [left-to-right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) mark should solve it.

```html
<div>36 و&lrm; 534 12</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a directionality marker

For LTR: `&#x200E;`

For RTL: `&#x200F;`

That's the only way I could get him to stand up right

```html
<div style="direction: rtl">&#x200E;534 12<span> و </span>36</div>
```

```html
<div style="direction: rtl">&#x200E;534 12 و &#x200F;36</div>
```

```html
<div style="direction: rtl">After text <div style="display: inline;">&#x200E;534 12 و&#x200F;36</div> Before text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but your answer does not work for the letter "و"

Comment: I made a change in my post

Answer (score 0):

The same as 54ka answered but it works even by removing span, anyway...
Can you explain why you used directionality marker :)

```html
<div style="direction: rtl">&#x200E;534 12 و 36</div>
```

```
<div style="direction: rtl">&#x200E;534 12 و 36</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if 36 and 534 12 are diffrence part, you can use seprate element for styling.